# Does oomkiller kick in at overcommit ratio

Tags: linux, ubuntu

If I configure the following

```
/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory = 2
/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio = 50
```

What happens if a program tries to allocate 50%? Does it kill the actual program only or can it somehow kill other processes like oom killer as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) for overcommit.

Basically, you can only use 50% of your RAM plus swap.  Any attempt to use more will result in the function allocating the memory getting an error. Take a look at /proc/meminfo for the `CommitLimit` line.

Comment: So in other words, once a program exceeds 50% of ram, it will terminate THAT program, no other program and oom-killer would never be triggered, did I get it correct? this is based on the configuration I posted in the original post

Comment: The kernel won’t terminate the process, the process will just get an unexpected memory error, which many programs do not handle well.